# Convert String to Float (with calculation within the string)

Tags: python, string, casting, type-conversion

I want a String to be converted to a float and if the string contains a calculation (like 1/3) it should calculate it and then convert.

I've tried by entering float(y), whereas y is my '+1/3'.

```
y = '+1/3'
float(y)
```

I expected the output to be something like '0.3333', but the error message i keep getting is "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '+1/3'".

Comment: can you guarantee that you will always have `/` in your string?

Comment: How complicated can the calculations be?

Comment: The `float` initializer doesn't evaluate expressions if the arugment passed to it is a string. What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with eval?

```
eval("+1/3")

output

0.3333333333333333
```

Comment: using eval is not a good practice, you read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are going to have `/` in your string, so you can use the following code:

```
numerator, denominator = '+1/3'.split('/')
y = float(numerator) / float(denominator)
```

Comment: what if operator changes? like * + -

Comment: @vbrises, can you provide a concrete input?